# communication between download manager and service

Tags: android

I want to create a download manager application so that it can show me the download process on the dialog of my application. The problem is that because my service and my main activity run on different process, they use different resource, when i destroy my main app, i will start the service to keep it downloading, but when i turn on my application again and the service is already started, i cannot update my process view since it is on a different process.

Can anyone show me a way to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: use a custom `ContentProvider` then

Comment: Thanks you, you are right, i tried with SQL, but i think it will be easier if i change my service to the same process as my activity since i they could share the same resource, am i right?

Comment: you can have your service in different process,  it is a normal situatuion when a client is in different process

Comment: That's true, but i think it is really hard to control and in my situation, it needs to share the same resource

Comment: it really doesn't make any difference if a `ContentProvider` is called from a different process or not